# modulo group defined by an algebraic relation

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

I am asked if $\{n, n^{2}, n^{3}\}$ forms a group under multiplication modulo $m$ where $m = n + n^{2} + n^{3}.$

As an example we see that $\{2, 4, 8\}$ does form a group modulo $14,$ with identity $8,$ but am stuck starting the proof for the general case. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Just an FYI, there is no need to edit the question to note it is answered. I know that you were just being proactive (and I appreciate it!) but all users can see on the main page when a question receives an answer.

Comment: If one of the answers is complete/answers your question good enough in your opinion, please accept it by clicking the green mark next to it, so this question becomes 'answered'.

Answer (score 3):

We work modulo $m=n+n^2+n^3$. Since $m|n^4-n$, we have that $n^4=n$. This implies* $n^3=1$, so $n^3$ is the identity. Also, when $x,y\in\{n,n^2,n^3\}=G$, we have $xy\in G$, because $xy=n^an^b=n^{a+b}=n^c$, where $c-1=a+b-1\mod 3$. Take for example $x=n^2$ and $y=n^3$. Then, $xy=n^5=n^4\cdot n=n\cdot n=n^2$. So in the exponent, we may subtract $3$ when it is at least $4$, making it the modulo $3$ remainder. (Note that we should take $n^3$ instead of $n^0$ here, since $n^3$ is already in our group.)

*this is not always true, but since we don't actually use that $n^3=1$ but only $n^4=n$, everything is fine.

Comment: Aren't you assuming that $n$ has an inverse mod $m$ when you say $n^{3} = 1$ ?

Comment: @slogn I think I am. Wasn't really sure about that while writing this. But Since we don't actually use $n^3=1$, everything is fine.

Comment: i like the $m | n^{4}-n$ catch, but could you also explain the closure again? Why is exactly $c$ a mod $3$ number?

Comment: oh i see, that's because $n^{4} = n$ correct?

Comment: @slogn yes, indeed.

Comment: Ok, so that shows closure, and i suppose the identity would be found by just trial error? Thanks for the clear explanation by the way

Comment: You can now use that $n^3\cdot n^k=n^{3+k}$ and since $k\geq 1$, that's equal to $n^k\in G$.

Comment: @Ragnar Your were on the right track. I show in my answer how the group arises from the cyclic group $\,\langle n\rangle = \{1,n,n^2\}\subset \Bbb Z/(n^3\!-1)\,$ by chasing some ring/group homomorphisms.

Answer (score 2):

Though one can verify this result by brute force calculation, one gains much more insight by examining the ring-theoretic structure governing the result. First, we have  factorizations

$\quad \smash[t]{(\color{#0a0}{\overbrace{n^3\!+\!n^2\!+\!n}^{\large m}})}(n\!-\!1)\, =\, n(n^3\!-1),\,$ and $\ G = \langle n\rangle =  \{1,n,n^2\}$ is a subgroup of $\,\Bbb Z/(n^3\!-1)\phantom{I^{I^{I^I}}}$

Chinese rem (CRT) $\,\Rightarrow\,  \Bbb Z/(n^3\!-1)\times \Bbb Z/n \,\cong\, \Bbb Z/n(n^3\!-1)\,\ $ by $\,\ (a,b)\to\, \color{#c00}{n^3} a + (1\!-\!n^3)\, b$

A ring hom is a group hom, therefore $\,(G,0)\to \color{#c00}{n^3}G \,$  remains a group in $\,R  = \Bbb Z/n(n^3\!-1),\,$ namely $\  n^3 G = {n^3}\{1,n,n^2\} = \{n^3,n^4,n^5\} = \{n^3,n,n^2\},\:$ since $\,\ n^4 = n\,$ in $\ \Bbb Z/(n^4\!-n)$

And, again, the image of $\ n^3 G \subset R\,$ remains a group in $\,R/\color{#0a0}m \,\cong\,\Bbb Z/\color{#0a0}m\ \ $ **QED**